# if condition is true goto the start of the program

Tags: php

I have this piece of code, basically if the "IF" statement in this code inside the function "minmax" is true, I want the program to start from the beginning.
I am not sure how to implement this logic, can someone please help

```
<?php 
// user to enter the number of heads
echo "Enter the number of heads: " . PHP_EOL;
// the script will wait here until the user has entered something and hit ENTER
$inhead = read_stdin();
// user to enter the number of legs
echo "Enter the number of legs: " . PHP_EOL;
// the script will wait here until the user has entered something and hit ENTER
$inleg = read_stdin();
function read_stdin()
{
    $fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   // open our file pointer to read from stdin
    $input = fgets($fr,128);        // read a maximum of 128 characters
    $input = rtrim($input);         // trim any trailing spaces.
    fclose ($fr);                   // close the file handle
    return $input;                  // return the text entered
}
//function to evalute if th euser has provided the right number of legs
function minmax($number)
{
    global $inhead,$inleg;
    $min = 2*$inhead;
    $max = 4*$inhead;
    if ($number<$min || $number>$max)
    {
        echo "please enter a number between $min and $max to get the correct result";
        echo "\n";
        echo "\n";
    }
}

//function to calculate the number of heads and legs
function get_the_result($noofheads,$nooflegs)
{   
    $x=($nooflegs-(2*$noofheads))/2;
    $y=$noofheads - $x;
    echo "The num of dogs are $x";
    //echo "/n";
    echo "The no of humans are $y";
}
minmax($inleg);
get_the_result($inhead,$inleg);
?>
```

Comment: One way to do it would be to encapsulate the user entry logic into a `while` loop. Just keep looping through the beginning part until the user enters something that breaks the loop and executes the rest of the program.

Comment: just reload the page with error message in session

Comment: @jason, could you please hilight the part of code that should be in the while loop?

Comment: user, it is *your* code that is here, so you are the programmer deciding which parts should be in while loops, Jason can give you guidance but **you** need to be able to take that guidance and apply it yourself to your own programming logic. It is not for an outside programmer to decide which parts of your code should be inside which loops.

Comment: thanks martin, i got it solved.@jason, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

You can use [goto](http://php.net/manual/ro/control-structures.goto.php):

```
location:
//...
goto location;
```

In your case, you need to check whether the functions exist to not try to declare them twice using `function_exists`.

While this is possible, I recommend that you should rewrite your code, as this approach is clearly unfeasible.

Comment: according to php document, if i use goto inside a function, i can only go to a block of code within that function and not outside of it, my block of code is outside the function, so i wont be able to use goto

Comment: @user3132672, you can do it with a wrapper or a try-catch handler, but once again, I do not recommend the usage of goto.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just reload the page if your validation does not satisfies.
Try using Session to display the error message.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
   echo $_SESSION['error'];
   unset($_SESSION['error']);
}

// user to enter the number of heads
echo "Enter the number of heads: " . PHP_EOL;
// the script will wait here until the user has entered something and hit ENTER
$inhead = read_stdin();
// user to enter the number of legs
echo "Enter the number of legs: " . PHP_EOL;
// the script will wait here until the user has entered something and hit ENTER
$inleg = read_stdin();
function read_stdin()
{
$fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   // open our file pointer to read from stdin
$input = fgets($fr,128);        // read a maximum of 128 characters
$input = rtrim($input);         // trim any trailing spaces.
fclose ($fr);                   // close the file handle
return $input;                  // return the text entered
}
//function to evalute if th euser has provided the right number of legs
function minmax($number)
{
global $inhead,$inleg;
$min = 2*$inhead;
$max = 4*$inhead;

if ($number<$min || $number>$max)
{
    $_SESSION['error'] = "please enter a number between $min and $max to get the correct result";
    echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'>");

}
}
//function to calculate the number of heads and legs
function get_the_result($noofheads,$nooflegs)
{   
$x=($nooflegs-(2*$noofheads))/2;
$y=$noofheads - $x;
echo "The num of dogs are $x";
//echo "/n";
echo "The no of humans are $y";
}
minmax($inleg);
get_the_result($inhead,$inleg);
?>
```

Note that header reload cannot be used here as some elements have already been echoed. And you can change the value of content to delay the time of page reload(the value is in seconds).

Comment: can you please edit the entire code, instead of just typing your part of the code

Comment: also, I am trying to run my code in console and not in a browser

Comment: the statements "please enter a number between..." is not being displayes when th e"IF" condition is true??any idea why

Comment: @arjun, if you can tell me whats wrng, I can upvote your answer

Comment: I think SESSION does not work in console so that is the problem.